# How to run php-cs-fixer from code?

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

I am writing a PHP command line app which generates some PHP code and wants to pass it thought the code style fixer before storing it to a file.

Is it possible to use [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) as a library and call it from the code ?

If no, is there any other solution to ensure that the generated code respects the PSR-2 standard ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it is. `magento/magento2` wants it to happen, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/10770, but I really wouldn't recommend it. If you do, however, take a look at the comment in this PR by Dariusz Ruminski, the maintainer of `friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer`: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/10770#issuecomment-327829883

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to:

1. Put your generated code into a temporary file.
2. Copy php-cs-fixer binary contents except the last line (second link here).
3. `Application::`[setAutoExit(false)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php#L329).
4. [call](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/2.5/php-cs-fixer#L53) `Application:run()` with `ArrayInput` and `BufferedOutput` and check return value (should be zero).

Or just `shell_exec` a whole command with its arguments.